# If I get an app that contains a monthly fee and I delete it, do i still have to pay?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, in-app-purchase

I got a palm reading app, not knowing that it included a monthly fee of $9.99. I have the iPhone 7 so I put my fingerprint in my phone. My fingerprint lets me pay for stuff, download apps, and open my phone. I accidentally gave the app my fingerprint not even thinking and I was so used to it. After I gave the my fingerprint, I saw what I did. I deleted the app right away and viewed its description, it said that it has a free 7-day trial so technically I didn't buy anything, I just allowed it to take money from me every month without my saying.

I don't have a Mac laptop and all the results I searched needed an Apple computer. I tried canceling my Visa card but it wouldn't allow me. I don't want $9.99 being taken away from me every month, is there anyway I can cancel it?

Comment: "Free trial subscription is automatically renewed unless cancelled 24 hours before the renewal" & " Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase".

Comment: Contact the developer and have them remove your account. Or you can call Apple Support and ask to speak with iTunes Support about the issue. 1-800-MY-APPLE (USA & Canada).

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel it at least 24 hours before the trial ends.

This is one area where Apple exerts control over developers allowing you to cancel subscriptions, directly,  easily and without any hassle.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039

You can use Apple support any time whether you still have the app installed or even own iPhone as you control payment methods and all subscriptions with your AppleID.

Otherwise (which almost certainly isn’t your case since biometrics started the trial out of the iOS App Store per your description), you need to cancel it from the developer if they have your payment method directly. (Or via your financial provider of course.)